# Losing data when rotate screen

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation

I have a little funny bug in my application. When the user rotates the screen I lose some of the data in my activity. Anyone that have an idea of why this happens?

Comment: The fastest solution I have found is this: <a>http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange</a>

Comment: A fun answer: you can force an orientation so that it can't rotate. If persistence is more important than allowing rotation, then it's preferred.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

By default, when the screen is rotated your Activity is killed and restarted.  To make sure no data is lost, you need to properly save and restore your data using the lifecycle methods.  See [Saving Persistent State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState).

Comment: Though some data _is_ saved by Android - `EditText` contents, for example.

Comment: @RivieraKid I don't know if you can depend on that though.  Have you seen anywhere official saying that that is the case?  I'd be worried about some off-brand phone changing the implementation slightly, if its not actually in the spec. The safest thing to do is assume nothing is saved.

Comment: @CherylSimon There is `freezesText` property that is set to `true` by default for `EditText`. Official documentation is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText.

Comment: I find it incredible how it all started being a simple rotation problem, solvable with a few "tricks", and a few years later we have a whole new design pattern (MVVM) to solve this simple issue.

Answer (score 77):

```
//Use onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and onRestoreInstanceState

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.   
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is  
  // killed and restarted.

  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);  
  savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);  
  savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);  
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");  

  // etc.  

  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);  
}  

//onRestoreInstanceState  

@Override  
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);  

  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.  
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.  

  boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");  
  double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");  
  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");  
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");  
}
```

**This is how you save your data when the system deletes it on rotation.**

Comment: I got it from here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state

Comment: Note! super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState) should be called before putting the values.

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState is not always called.

Answer (score 15):

## More Detail

People have already provided the code. So I am going to add more details on that.

#### What happens when screen rotates?

When the screen rotates the configuration of the Activity changes so System looks for a more suitable resource for the Activity. For this purpose System kills the instance of the activity and recreates a new instance of the Activity.

#### How does System creates a new Instance?

System tries to recreate the instance using a set of saved data of old Activity instance known as **instance state**. InstanceState is a collection of **Key-Value** Pair stored in a `Bundle` object.

#### System saved some data automatically

By default System saves the View objects in the Bundle for example.

- Text in EditText
- Scroll position in a ListView etc

If you want to store more data which should survive orientation change. You should override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.

#### Use onSaveInstaneState correctly

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

> So by mistake if you forget to call 
>   super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState) the default behavior
>   will not work ie Text in `EditText` will not save.
>   If you don't believe me [check this out](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/blob/182c333b4e295ade0affc5594154d2612dca93ca/Activity%20Related%20Stuff/app/src/main/java/rohitksingh/com/activityrelatedstuff/FirstActivity.java#L60)

#### Which method to use to restore state ?

Many people get confused including me. Should I choose

- `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

OR

- `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

**It does not matter**. Both methods receive the same bundle in the parameter. The only difference is that you need to provide a null check in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method. But if you are going to use `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, **use it carefully**

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
}
```

> Always call `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` so that
>   System restore the View hierarchy by default

Answer (score 8):

Here is a variation on @jaisonDavis's helpful answer:

```
int myInt;
String myString;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verses);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        myInt = intent.getIntExtra("MyIntIntentKey", DEFAULT_INT);
        myString = intent.getStringExtra("MyStringIntentKey", DEFAULT_STRING);

    } else { // savedInstanceState has saved values

        myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyIntKey");
        myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyStringKey");
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    savedInstanceState.putInt("MyIntKey", myInt);
    savedInstanceState.putString("MyStringKey", myString);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

In this example the variables get initialized from an `Intent` on the first time the activity is created, but after that they get initialized from `savedInstanceState` (like when the orientation changes).

Answer (score 7):

In the **AndroidManifest.xml** add the following code

`<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            >`

Answer (score 4):

Android has introduced `ViewModel` which can store Complex Objects when Screen is rotated. 
The `ViewModel` class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way. The `ViewModel` class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.

Please refer to docs

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your issue of retaining state, but it only works for a `Fragment` and not a standard `Activity` unfortunately.

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

Call this in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Where do you get that method from?

Comment: OP question tag is  **activity**  not **fragment**

Answer (score 2):

In the AndroidManifest.xml add the following code

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            >
```

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

configChanges solve my problem

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVM pattern and use your ViewModel to save your data. So when you rotate your device you won't be worry about losing your data because you isolated your data in the ViewModel and that means your data won't be affected by activity lifecycle.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

A “ViewModel” is a class designed to survive configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation) and can preserve the information necessary for the View. When “View” (i.e. fragment/activity) is destroyed by changing the configuration or rotation of the device, its “ViewModel” will not be destroyed and a new instance of View will be reconnected to the same “ViewModel”.

This is what the code in **ViewModel** might look like so that View can save the data:

```
private boolean mSomeBooleanData = false;

public boolean getSomeBooleanData(){
    return mSomeBooleanData;
}

public void setSomeBooleanData (boolean data) {
    mSomeBooleanData = data;
}
```

Now somewhere in the **Activity/Fragment** class, calling these methods from the ViewModel we can save the data we want to save during rotation using:

```
mViewModel.setSomeBooleanData(true);
```

Then when recreating the Activity/Fragment class in the onResume () method, we can look for that saved data from the ViewModel and do something with it:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
   
    if (mViewModel.getSomeBooleanData()){
        //...Do something when saved data is True
    } else {
        //...Do something when saved data is False
    }
}
```