# Contents of action bar not shown

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am using action bar fragment in my app.When screen rotates contents of action bar lost please suggest how to retain them. Here is the code i am doing for that

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if(currentDisplayedCase != null) {
            outState.putInt(DISPLAY_CASE_KEY, currentDisplayedCase.intValue());

        }
        outState.putString(ACTION_BAR_TEXT, textView1.getText().toString());
    }
```

and in onCreate method

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null&&savedInstanceState.containsKey(ACTION_BAR_TEXT))
        textView1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(ACTION_BAR_TEXT, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

When device is rotated, the activity is restarted.

For proper solution you can see following link

[Losing data when rotate screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123407/losing-data-when-rotate-screen)

It will help you understand why your data is lost and how to recover it.

Comment: i am doing the same now but not getting content on config change

Answer (score 0):

you need to add following in your activity declaration in manifest file android:configChanges="orientation", i. e.

`<activity
            android:name=".myActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/txt_app_name"
            android:theme="@style/myTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

this means that you will be handling orientation changes in your activity.