# Marker on the map disappears when orientation changes

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tabs

I've implmenented a simple Activity which contains two tabs. These tabs are associated with Fragments: the first one is a `MapFragment`, the second is a `ListFragment`.
I overrid the `onCreate` method in this way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.path_summary);

    final ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab()
            .setText("Map")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment>(
                    this, "map", com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.class)));

    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab()
            .setText("List")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<com.example.northfinder.PathListFragment>(
                    this, "list", com.example.northfinder.PathListFragment.class)));


    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }

}
```

Then I need to write in the map (adding a marker), so I've override the onResume method:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment f = fm.findFragmentByTag("map");
        if(f!= null && f.isAdded())
        setUpMapIfNeeded((MapFragment)f);
    }
```

where `setUpIfNeeded` is defined below:

```
private static void setUpMapIfNeeded(MapFragment mMapFragment) {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

    }
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.clear()
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

All works good. The marker is correctly added in the MapFragment when the Activity starts, and when I change tab and then I come back in the first tab the marker is yet visible.

I have just a problem: when orientation changes the marker disappears. Why?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123407/losing-data-when-rotate-screen

Comment: But when orientation changes the Activity should be recreated so both onCreate and onResume should be executed. Right?

Comment: Uhm I think that in my question I was missing an important thing. I.e. I've declared mMap variable as static.

Comment: Yes I was right: I have removed the static keyword from mMap variable and now it works :D

Comment: glad to solve problem your self

Comment: I have partially soled the problem. Because, when I select the second tab then change orientation and then come back to the first tab the marker disappears. I solved the problem only when I'm on the first tab and I change rotation :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding this code inside the callbacks `onTabSelected` and `onTabReselected`

```
if(mTag.compareToIgnoreCase("map")==0)
{
    setUpMapIfNeeded((MapFragment)mFragment);
}
```