# orientation changes after camera takes photo

Tags: android

I can take photos using default camera app.
But just after getting image data within onActivityResult  orientation changes and all data vanish (image data). I do not want to force users to use app in landscape mode.

so How can I store image path coming from camera intent even if orientation changes

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
if (requestCode == CAPTURE) {

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<21){
                    lastPath=data.getStringExtra("path");
                }else{
                    lastPath=getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()) // set lastPath
                }
}
```

Then I try to store **lastPath**

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    if(lastPath!=null){
        outState.putString("path",lastPath);

    }

}
```

Finally I try to get **lastPath** sent from onSaveInstanceState after restart of the app

```
 @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    String path=savedInstanceState.getString("path");

    Log.v("path",path);

    // --> throws NullPointerException

}
```

as you see it throws Exception

Comment: you need to save the URI obtain in from camera result into the bundle state. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123407/losing-data-when-rotate-screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Losing data when rotate screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123407/losing-data-when-rotate-screen)

Comment: Please read the question again. I've edited it