# Java andorid painting my view always is clearing when I rotate my phone

Tags: android

I created a painting view and when I rotate my phone my paiting always is clearing and I do not have idea why is clearing .

This is my whole activity :

```
public class SignatureActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {

    File mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private FrameLayout drawerBox;
    private Button save, clear;
    private DrawerView mv;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private boolean existingSign;
    private Intent intent;
    private String signature;
    private File imagesDir;

    private ArrayList<MotionEvent> motionEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<MotionEvent> auxMotionEvents = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_act_lay);
        existingSign = getIntent().hasExtra(getPackageName() + "_signaturePath");
        initializeView();
        setListeners();
        Intent iin = getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            signature = (String) b.get("signaturePath");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

    private void initializeView() {
        drawerBox = this.findViewById(R.id.drawerContainer);
        save = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        clear = findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);
        if (existingSign) {
            mv = new DrawerView(this, BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent()
                    .getStringExtra(getPackageName() + "_signaturePath")));
        } else {
            mv = new DrawerView(this);
        }
        mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        mv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        drawerBox.addView(mv);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    }

//    @Override
//    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//
//        mCurrentPhotoPath = (File) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(MY_CURRENT_PHOTO_PATH_KEY);
//        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
//
//        outState.putSerializable(MY_CURRENT_PHOTO_PATH_KEY, mCurrentPhotoPath);
//        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
//    }

    private void setListeners() {
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!mv.isSigned()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignatureActivity.this, R.string.empty_sign, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);
                    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                    String name = "sign_" + currentDateandTime;
                    Bitmap bitmap = mv.getDrawingCache();
                    File imagesFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File(imagesFolder, name + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                        ostream.close();
                        mv.invalidate();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    }
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.putExtra(getPackageName() + "_signaturePath", file.getPath());
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

                    finishWithResult(file.getPath());
                    if (signature != null) {
                        File file1 = new File(signature);
                        file1.delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mv.clear();
                mv.setIsSigned(false);
            }
        });

    }

    private void finishWithResult(String path) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        intent.putExtra("path", path);
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        return false;
    }


    public class DrawerView extends View {
        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private Path mPath;
        private Paint mBitmapPaint;
        private float mX, mY, sX, sY;
        private boolean isSigned = false;
        private static final String EXTRA_EVENT_LIST = "event_list";
        private static final String EXTRA_STATE = "instance_state";
//        private ArrayList<MotionEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<MotionEvent>(100);

        public DrawerView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            setSaveEnabled(true);
        }

        public DrawerView(Context c, Bitmap bitmap) {
            super(c);
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            mBitmap = bitmap;
            setSaveEnabled(true);
        }


        @Override
        public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {



            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable(EXTRA_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_EVENT_LIST, motionEvents);

            return bundle;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
            if (state instanceof Bundle) {

                auxMotionEvents = new ArrayList<>();
                motionEvents = new ArrayList<>();

                Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
                super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(EXTRA_STATE));
                auxMotionEvents = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_EVENT_LIST);
                if (auxMotionEvents == null) {
                    auxMotionEvents = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                return;
            }
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }
        public void setIsSigned(boolean isSigned) {
            this.isSigned = isSigned;
        }

        public boolean isSigned() {
            return isSigned;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            if (motionEvents != null) {
                for (MotionEvent motionEvent : motionEvents) {
                    performTouch(motionEvent);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        public void clear() {
            setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            invalidate();
        }

        private void drawDot(float x, float y) {
            mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, 2.0f, mPaint);
        }

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
            sX = x;
            sY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            mPath.reset();
        }


        private void performTouch(MotionEvent event) {
            this.isSigned = true;
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
//                    motionEvents.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
//                    motionEvents.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (x == sX && y == sY) {
                        drawDot(x, y);
                    }
                    touch_up();
//                    motionEvents.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));

                    break;
            }
            invalidate();
            motionEvents.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));

//            motionEventsList.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            motionEvents.add(event);

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    performTouch(event);

            }

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

When I roatet my phone this function is call :
onSizeChanged and when I debug this I see that motionEvents is empty it does not have any object inside , My activity never call this method :onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState. I do not have idea what I did wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you rotate your device your `OnCreate()` is get called. i.e. Activity is restarted on device rotate

Comment: @AshishKudale so what I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix. Add the screen orientation like in the below example in you AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SignatureActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_yourTitle"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Its' the android **lifecycle** being recreated when you rotate the screen, that's why you are facing that problem. By putting it to only *portrait*, you can't recreate it by rotating the phone.

Comment: No becouse I do not want block a rotate a phone

Comment: @tompok then go and see this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5123441/8856315)

Comment: so what I have to do ?