# Preserving Value When Orientation Changes

Tags: java, android, android-orientation

I am developing a very basic Android App that adds a number in *TextView* whenever I hit the *Button*. The digit showing in *TextView* is also preserved when the *orientation of the Mobile changes* using the *onSaveInstanceState()* and *onRestoreInstanceState()* functions.

The ***problem*** is when **orientation changes** the value is **preserved** but when the **Button is pressed once again after the changing of the orientation it again starts the counting from 0 rather then starting it from the preserved value.**

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView showValue;
    int counter=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CounterValue);
    }


    public void countIN(View view)
    {
        counter++;
        showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("my_text", showValue.getText().toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        showValue.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("my_text"));
    }
 }
```

Thank You for your response.

Comment: your counter remain 0 after orientation changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
counter=Integer.parseInt(savedInstanceState.getString("my_text"));
```

inside onRestoreInstanceState method

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    showValue.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("my_text"));
    counter=Integer.parseInt(savedInstanceState.getString("my_text"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save and get data using several methods

**First** If your data is small, then you can use `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` .. for details follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-save-an-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state#151940) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123407/losing-data-when-rotate-screen#5123441)

**Second** if you have too much data to store, then use ViewModel instead; [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e) is a tutorial that you can start from.