# Landscape Orientation - How to preserve data and layout attributes?

Tags: android, xml, layout, orientation

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I have been trying to allow my device to keep the activity from wiping data every-time I change orientation from portrait to landscape.

I found that I can do so by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the activity field in my `AndroidManifest.xml` as can be seen below:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" >
...
</activity>
```

However, by doing so, it does not consider the layout changes which I made in my `/res/layout-land/main.activity.xml`

If I delete the `android:configChanges` modifications made, it applies all changes made in `res/layout-land/activity_main.xml`

I would like clarification on:

1. Why is the layout not being read if I use `android:configChanges`?
2. Is there a way I can make the orientation not delete the data created while maintaining the layout attributes?

My full  XML code for the landscape view is as below:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="80dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_team_a"
                        android:textSize="28sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_0"
                        android:textSize="46sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:onClick="addOneTeamA"
                        android:text="@string/bt_score_plus_1" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_fouls"
                        android:textSize="28sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_a_foul"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_0"
                        android:textSize="46sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:onClick="addOneFoulTeamA"
                        android:text="@string/bt_foul_plus_1" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_penalty"
                        android:textSize="28sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_a_penalty"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_0"
                        android:textSize="46sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:onClick="addOnePenaltyTeamA"
                        android:text="@string/bt_penalty_plus_1" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_team_b"
                        android:textSize="28sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_b"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_0"
                        android:textSize="46sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:onClick="addOneTeamB"
                        android:text="@string/bt_score_plus_1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_fouls"
                        android:textSize="28sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_b_foul"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_0"
                        android:textSize="46sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:onClick="addOneFoulTeamB"
                        android:text="@string/bt_foul_plus_1" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_penalty"
                        android:textSize="28sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_b_penalty"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/text_0"
                        android:textSize="46sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:onClick="addOnePenaltyTeamB"
                        android:text="@string/bt_penalty_plus_1" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:onClick="resetDetails"
                android:text="@string/bt_reset" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT**

If possible, would like to have a XML solution without the need to tinker on the Java code.

Comment: Are you writing your business logic in the activity class?

Comment: @NathanGetachew, I forgot to revert back to you. Apologise. Yes, all logic is being implemented in my main activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing, it seems the issue is not in the `android:configChanges` but the location of the opening tag of `RelativeLayout` which caused all this issue. I just had to change it to the below and it works:

My XML layout was fixed by doing the following:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout ...>

            <LinearLayout...>

                <LinearLayout
                    ...
                </LinearLayout>

                <View ... />

                <LinearLayout
                  ...
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        <RelativeLayout...>

            <Button .../>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Below is the detailed solution with all code changes done, including my XML file:

Update the code in `AndroidManifest.xml` file to include the additional code of `android:configChanges` as shown below in the activity tag:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" >
...
</activity>
```

Then I had to go to my `activity_main.xml` and change the location of the `RelativeLayout` opening tag as it has been the cause of having some buttons to be *hidden* when orientation from portrait to landscape was invoked.

The old code format:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout ...>

        <RelativeLayout...> <-- remove it from here

            <LinearLayout...>

                <LinearLayout
                    ...
                </LinearLayout>

                <View ... />

                <LinearLayout
                  ...
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


            <Button .../>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My XML layout was fixed by doing the following:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout ...>

            <LinearLayout...>

                <LinearLayout
                    ...
                </LinearLayout>

                <View ... />

                <LinearLayout
                  ...
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        <RelativeLayout...> <-- add it here

            <Button .../>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The full working XML code is below:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_team_a"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_0"
                    android:textSize="46sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:onClick="addOneTeamA"
                    android:text="@string/bt_score_plus_1" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_fouls"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_a_foul"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_0"
                    android:textSize="46sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:onClick="addOneFoulTeamA"
                    android:text="@string/bt_foul_plus_1" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_penalty"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_a_penalty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_0"
                    android:textSize="46sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:onClick="addOnePenaltyTeamA"
                    android:text="@string/bt_penalty_plus_1" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_team_b"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_0"
                    android:textSize="46sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:onClick="addOneTeamB"
                    android:text="@string/bt_score_plus_1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_fouls"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_b_foul"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_0"
                    android:textSize="46sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:onClick="addOneFoulTeamB"
                    android:text="@string/bt_foul_plus_1" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_penalty"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_b_penalty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/text_0"
                    android:textSize="46sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:onClick="addOnePenaltyTeamB"
                    android:text="@string/bt_penalty_plus_1" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:onClick="resetDetails"
                android:text="@string/bt_reset" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **savedInstanceState** or android have introduced **ViewModel** to manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way.

for more info
[Android ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

[Can also refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47770372/7209822)

Comment: Thank you for the details. I get from this to deal with this issue I will have to use some Java code and not just XML, correct?

Was trying to look for a way to do so with XML only, if possible.

Comment: How to you assigning value to your Views in your XML.? Via Java or Kotlin Code ..right?

Have a look at the **Android activity life cycle**...

what happens when you rotate you phone.

Comment: Apologies, will rephrase what I meant. I want to leave the Java code which automatically gets created by Android Studio untouched and only modify the XML. I understand everyone modifies the Java code which seems to be the optimal solution for most however that is not what I want to do right now with my current code. Is there a way other than what I have mentioned in my main post?