# RecyclerView swipe functionality breaks after orientation change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I created a RecyclerView that refreshes its list based on a database call.  Each row has an options menu that is revealed when the user swipes.  My original issue was that **after an orientation change**, the swipe gestures no longer revealed the menu.  I hit all my expected breakpoints with `onCreateViewHolder()` and the `onSwipe()`.  However, the row remained as the `HIDE_MENU` view type after swiping.

So I tried to introduce LiveData to persist the state of the list after orientation changes.  The RecyclerView was still created and populated with items but now the swipe gesture crashes the application with an error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Do I need to use LiveData to fix the original issue of preserving my swipe functionality after orientation changes?  If not, please can someone explain why the item view types are no longer updated after orientation changes.

If I do need to use a ViewModel, what am I doing that is causing the list adapter not to receive the updated list?

### HistoryFragment

```kotlin
class HistoryFragment : Fragment() {
    private val historyViewModel by activityViewModels<HistoryViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false)
        historyViewModel.getHistoryList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            refreshRecyclerView(it)
        })
        return root
    }
    
    private fun updateHistoryList() {
        val dbHandler = MySQLLiteDBHandler(requireContext(), null)
        val historyList = dbHandler.getHistoryList() as MutableList<HistoryObject>
        historyViewModel.setHistoryList(historyList)
    }

    private fun refreshRecyclerView(historyList: MutableList<HistoryObject>) {
        val historyListAdapter = HistoryListAdapter(historyList)
        val callback = HistorySwipeHelper(historyListAdapter)
        val helper = ItemTouchHelper(callback)
        history_list.adapter = historyListAdapter
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(history_list)
    }
    
    private fun setupSort() {
        val sortSpinner: Spinner = history_list_controls_sort
        sortSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                updateHistoryList()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(
        view: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        setupSort()
    }
}
```

### HistoryListAdapter

```kotlin
const val SHOW_MENU = 1
const val HIDE_MENU = 2

class HistoryListAdapter(private var historyData: MutableList<HistoryObject>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == SHOW_MENU) {
            val inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.history_list_view_row_items_menu, parent, false)
            MenuViewHolder(inflatedView)
        } else {
            val inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.history_list_view_row_items_description, parent, false)
            HistoryItemViewHolder(inflatedView)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (historyData[position].showMenu) {
            SHOW_MENU
        } else {
            HIDE_MENU
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return historyData.count()
    }

    fun showMenu(position: Int) {
        historyData.forEachIndexed { idx, it ->
            if (it.showMenu) {
                it.showMenu = false
                notifyItemChanged(idx)
            }
        }
        historyData[position].showMenu = true
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item: HistoryObject = historyData[position]
        if (holder is HistoryItemViewHolder) {
            holder.bindItem(item)
            ...
        }

        if (holder is MenuViewHolder) {
            holder.bindItem(item)
            ...
        }
    }

    class HistoryItemViewHolder(v: View, private val clickHandler: (item: HistoryObject) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        private var view: View = v
        private var item: HistoryObject? = null

        fun bindItem(item: HistoryObject) {
            this.item = item
            ...
        }
    }

    class MenuViewHolder(v: View, private val deleteHandler: (item: HistoryObject) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        private var view: View = v
        private var item: HistoryObject? = null

        fun bindItem(item: HistoryObject) {
            this.item = item
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

### HistorySwipeHelper

```kotlin
class HistorySwipeHelper(private val adapter: HistoryListAdapter) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean { return false }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        adapter.showMenu(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
    }

    override fun getSwipeThreshold(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Float {
        return 0.1f
    }
}
```

### HistoryViewModel

```kotlin
class HistoryViewModel(private var historyListHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    fun getHistoryList(): LiveData<MutableList<HistoryObject>> {
        return historyListHandle.getLiveData(HISTORY_LIST_KEY)
    }

    fun setHistoryList(newHistoryList: MutableList<HistoryObject>) {
        historyListHandle.set(HISTORY_LIST_KEY, newHistoryList)
    }

    companion object {
        const val HISTORY_LIST_KEY = "MY_HISTORY_LIST"
    }
}
```

### Activity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val historyViewModel: HistoryViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(HistoryViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        historyViewModel.setHistoryList(mutableListOf())
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.  If this question is too broad I can try again and decompose it.

Comment: Did you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56815186/10954249

Comment: I saw this solution but had some doubts because I saw people saying it was a bandaid (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/2016353).  It does fix my immediate issue.  I don't know if it is appropriate for my use case but I'll give it a go.  Thank you

Comment: Just an update that the swipe gesture functionality is still broken after adding this.

Comment: Do you preserve the activity on orientation change in the manifest?

Comment: If I understand correctly how LIveData works then you have to have something like val historyList: MutableLiveData<HistoryObject> inside your HistoryViewModel

Comment: Change Your ViewModel getHistoryList from LiveData<MutableList<HistoryObject>> to LiveData<HistoryObject>  Here the doc: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#the_advantages_of_using_livedata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create new adapter every time you get an update of your history list. Keep using the same adapter, just update the items and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the state (of course you can use different methods to notify about the insertion/deletion/etc, but make it work with `notifyDataSetChanged()` first).

I'm pretty sure this will fix the issue.

Comment: I think there is no match difference between setAdapter(new Adapter) and notifyDataSetChaged()